# Reordenando AutoIncrement no SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, auto-incremento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Eae galera, tipo criei uma tabela de ID com o Auto Increment, verificando a tabela ví que Bugou, tem algum comando no SQL que reordene do valor 1,2,3,4 ao ultimo? só mais por questão de reorganização.
Obrigado.

Comment: Outras tabelas dependem desses registros? ela pode ser recriada?... Se você quer manter essa ordem "limpa" e manipula seus registros, não deveria deixar o identity ligado

Comment: Entenda que um campo chave primária com auto increment não é um campo que precise estar organizado aos olhos, entenda ele como um valor único na sua tabela, que é uma garantia de um registro único para o banco, por isso mexer nesses valores não é uma boa ideia.E o banco não "reordena", você pode mudar a semente do incremento e forçar um valor qualquer, mas de novo, melhor deixar isso por conta do banco, se preocupe com os campos de "valor" para o negócio, como descrições, datas, etc

Comment: mas se ainda quiser "mexer" na semente, veja o comando [dbcc checkident](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Nenhuma tabela depende desse registro, porém o ID é o campo de "Referencia na Identificação no aquivo morto, em possíveis consultas ou identificação no ambiente, no caso de recriar, no  caso os dados que já estão inserido não pode haver perda de dados não?

Comment: @RicardoPontual esse comando verifiquei ele, vai completar os espaços que ficou vazio entre o meio correto explicar?

Comment: Ele não vai completar, ele muda o próximo valor do identity. Se por exemplo você quer que gere do 1 ao 177, precisar voltar ele pra 1, até que atinja o 177, depois mudar novamente (bem ruim), ou criar uma nova tabela, com identity certinho, começando do 1 e inserir os valores dessa tabela lá, deixando tudo "em ordem", depois você muda os nomes das tabelas. Precisa excluir chaves estrangeiras para fazer isso

Comment: Ou grava os dados em uma temporária, dá um truncate na tabela e re-insere esses dados da temporária... Mas como o @RicardoPontual comentou, você não deveria estar se preocupando com a estética e sim com a integridade de seus dados

Comment: Sim, a ideia do @LeandroAngelo é boa, e não esqueça de depois de apagar os registros, mudar a semente do identity para 1

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, foi de grande ajuda agora a informação que vocês me passaram. Obrigado.

Comment: @RicardoPontual o truncate já vai reiniciar o seed do identity

Comment: interessante @LeandroAngelo, não sabia disso, mais uma pra caixa de conhecimentos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Conforme foi discutido nos comentários, você não deveria se preocupar com essa questão estética do identificador mas sim com a integridade dos dados.

No cenário onde essa `Primary Key` não é `Foreign Key` de nenhuma outra ou valor até mesmo valor para outra referência fraca. Você pode armazenar o conteúdo atual da tabela, executar um truncate e repopular ela novamente.

```
/* Criando a estrutura de armazenamento sem o ID */
DECLARE @TabelaTemporaria TABLE(
    Status VARCHAR(50)
    /* restante das suas colunas */
) 

/* Armazenando o conteúdo existente na [SUA_TABELA] para a @TabelaTemporaria */
INSERT INTO @TabelaTemporaria ([Status] /* restante das suas colunas */)
(SELECT Status /* demais campos sem o Id */FROM [SUA_TABELA])

/* Limpando a [SUA_TABELA] */
TRUNCATE TABLE [SUA_TABELA]

/* Populando novamente a tabela original */
INSERT INTO [SUA_TABELA] (idSistema)
(SELECT * FROM @TabelaTemporaria)
```